# Send Notification from Firebase to Android App when Product Expiry Date is Near

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on an Android app that uses several `Firebase` functions. In the real-time database. I have a date (expiry date of product) and I need to notify the user when that expiry date stored in Firebase real-time database is nearing (for e.g, 1 day before the expiry date in the real-time database). Here is what my app looks like.

[image]

how can we send notifications to user?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no Firebase database trigger which you can use to achieve this. You'll have to write and schedule a cloud function which checks the expiry. The function calls FCM end-point to send notification to the user. Refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) link for technical details.

Note : You'll have to be on the Blaze plan to use the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting up a cronjob on your server. Schedule it to run every hour or so.